# angular ui router state with search elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Main question: is it possible to use `$state.go()` with custom search elements populated by `$location.search(e,v)`? Or maybe I need to use `$location.path()` each time I would like to make such transition?

Why do I need it: I have a view, with a few selects (all of them have a default null value), and it would be nice, if every change on those selects would change the location (f.e. list of partners `/partners/list?branch=branch01&role=seller`). But by using `$state.go()` I can only use `$stateParams` (which are defined inside state url) - but that does not satisfy me and I would like to have an action that changes the state directly to f.e. `/partners/list?role=seller`.

I would like the solution to use `$location.search(e,v)` because all the parameters are optional, so I can't prepare a state that can take any set of search parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply search elements using `.go()`

```js
// Here's a skeleton app.  Fork this plunk, or create your own from scratch.
var app = angular.module('demonstrateissue', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state({ 
    name: 'home', 
    url: '/home?param1&param2', 
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {
      $scope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }, 
    template: 'state params: <pre>{{ $stateParams | json }}</pre>'});
});


// Adds state change hooks; logs to console.
app.run(function($state, $rootScope, $location) {
      $rootScope.someparams = function() { $state.go('home', { param1: 'foo', param2: 'bar' }); };
      $rootScope.otherparams = function() { $state.go('home', { param1: 'wat', param2: 'oy!' }); };
      $rootScope.location = $location.url;
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(evt, extra) { 
$rootScope.location = extra;
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.11/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="demonstrateissue">
      <a href="#" ng-click="someparams()">Some params</a>
      <a href="#" ng-click="otherparams()">Other params</a>
      <div ui-view>
        ui-view not populated
      </div>  
      <pre>{{ location }}</pre>
    </body>
```